# Make div scroll to bottom automatically (react)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

I'm currently working on a chat app for school, but I want to make it scroll to the bottom automatically as most chat apps do. I've tried every solution I can find so far, and I have only been getting react errors. I'm new to react so there could be some mistakes I don't realize I'm making. Here is what I have

```
class Messages extends React.Component {
    updateScroll() {
    let element = document.querySelector(".messages");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
render() {
    const messages = store.getState().messages.map((msg) => {
      this.updateScroll();
      return (
        <Message
          name={msg.displayName}
          message={msg.text}
          time={msg.timestamp}
          pic={msg.pic}
          key={msg.timestamp}
          clas={msg.who}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="messages">
        <div className="chat">
        </div>
        <div className="sendMessage">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Message epic channel"
            className="pendingMessage"
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyDown}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleMessageSend}>Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Messages;
```

Here is my GitHub link if you want the full code as well. https://github.com/dougalcaleb/react-chat-app

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should do this with css

The chatbox content need the following markup, where the content is aligned to bottom.

```
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: Would that not put the most current messages at the top? That would solve the problem of not being visible but it's not what I'm going for.

Comment: Well, I'm a little bit confused as to why that worked but that was an incredibly easy fix haha. Thanks for your help

Comment: Lol, no problem at all! thanks for rep points

Answer (score 0):

You should use refs instead of document query

```js
class Messages extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.messagesRef = React.createRef()
    }

    updateScroll() {
      this.messagesRef.current.scrollTo(0, this.messagesRef.current.scrollHeight)
    }

   render() {
    const messages = store.getState().messages.map((msg) => {
      this.updateScroll();
      return (
        <Message
          name={msg.displayName}
          message={msg.text}
          time={msg.timestamp}
          pic={msg.pic}
          key={msg.timestamp}
          clas={msg.who}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div ref={this.messagesRef} className="messages">
        <div className="chat">
        </div>
        <div className="sendMessage">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Message epic channel"
            className="pendingMessage"
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyDown}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleMessageSend}>Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Messages;
```

Can you try that using ref + scrollTo ?

Answer (score 0):

create a dummy div below messages.

```
<div ref={messagesEndRef}></div>
```

```js
    const messagesEndRef = useRef(null)

    const [msglist, setMsglist] = useState([]);
```

if msglist is the list of new messages, use useEffect to handle the change.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
    }, [msglist])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `updateScroll` function inside `componentDidMount` if you are just fetching messages from state.

You can also use a ref to your `message` div and get the height from there instead of using `querySelector`